# v-model для группы checkbox компонентов

Tags: vue.js

Необходимо реализовать v-model для группы checkbox. Код который я написал:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  // CheckboxComponent
    components: {
      CheckboxComponent: {
        props: ['value', 'label'],
        template: `
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                :checked="value"
                @input="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)"
              >
              <span>{{ label }}</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        `
      }
    },
  // End of CheckboxComponent
  
  data() {
    return {
      checked: [],
      someData: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Name 0' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Name 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Name 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Name 3' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Name 4' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Name 5' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}#app{padding:1rem;}ul{list-style:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in someData" :key="item.id">
    
      <checkbox-component :label="item.name" v-model="checked"/>
      
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  {{ checked }}
  
</div>
```

На данный момент, получилось что-то реализовать, но мне возвращает `true/false` всех checkbox, а нужно чтобы в массив `checked: []`, попадал `label`, или еще лучше - `value`, активного `checkbox-component`

[Результат](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B) который нужно получить, но с кастомным компонентом.
Прошу помочь с решением!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявляете внутри вложенного компонента в `data` свойство (допустим) `checkedP`:

```
data() {
    return {
      checkedP: false
    }
  },
```

в `computed` объявляете:

```
computed: {
    checked: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(val) {
        this.checkedP = val
      }
    }
  },
```

, этот метод будет формировать текущее актуальное состояние этого вложенного компонента и в итоге либо вернет текущее состояние (полученное из `props`), либо модифицирует его (если произойдет событие).

`template` оформляете следующим образом:

```
template: `
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            v-model="checked"
            :value="item"
            @change="onChange"
          >
          <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    `,
```

Соответственно добавляете метод для обработки события на `input`:

```
methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      this.$emit('input', this.checkedP)
    }
  }
```

Таким образом, инициируя событие изменения состояния `input`, вы вызываете метод `onChange`, в результате работы которого в родительский компонент будет отправлено новое состояние текущего компонента (заметьте за это состояние отвечает метод `checked` из `computed` текущего вложенного компонента), в свою очередь родитель синхронизирует это состояние со своими моделями, а именно `v-model="checked"`

Привожу ваш пример с указанными модификациями.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  // CheckboxComponent
  components: {
    CheckboxComponent: {
      props: ['value', 'item'],
      data() {
        return {
          checkedP: false
        }
      },
      computed: {
        checked: {
          get() {
            return this.value
          },
          set(val) {
            this.checkedP = val
          }
        }
      },
      template: `
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                v-model="checked"
                :value="item"
                @change="onChange"
              >
              <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        `,
      methods: {
        onChange(e) {
          this.$emit('input', this.checkedP)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // End of CheckboxComponent

  data: {
    checked: [],
    someData: [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Name 0'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Name 2'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Name 3',
        checked: true
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Name 4'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Name 5'
      }
    ]

  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  padding: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pre {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in someData" :key="item.id">

      <checkbox-component :item="item" v-model="checked" />

    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="pre">
    {{ checked }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, действительно, не подумал про get/set, благодарю!